# Multi Regional Behavioral Triggers

Tags: marketing-cloud, behavioral-triggers

I am working with a Behavioral Trigger catalogue with multiple regions so names, price, image link all have a different value depending on the customer's country. e.g. One of the product name headers is locale_cs-CZ_ProductName, and price is similar locale_en-DE_RegularPrice.

I'm using the out-of-the-box content block as a guide.

```
%%[
  Set @data = Concat('{"trigger_payload":"', data, '"}')
  Set @mid = memberid
]%%

<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core", "1");
  try {
    var defaults = {
      "link" : "Link",
      "image_link" : "ImageLink",
      "product_code" : "ProductCode",
      "name" : "Name", 
      "regular_price" : "RegularPrice", 
      "sale_price" : "SalePrice", 
      "sku_id" : "SkuID"
    };
    
    // Data from block settings
    var settings = {"fields":{"image_link":"ImageLink","name":"ProductName","regular_price":"RegularPrice"},"maxItems":3,"sortBy":"item_order","sortDirection":"desc","desktopCols":1,"mobileCols":0,"useSalePricing":false};
    var markupFragments = {
      "header" : '<div class="wrapper" align="center" style="--max-table-width: 600px; --max-column-width: 310px; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #ffffff;"><div class="webkit" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;"><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><table width="600" align="center"><tr><td><![endif]--><table class="outer" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0; font-family: sans-serif; color: #333333; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; max-width: 600px;"><tr><td class="multi-column" style="padding: 0; text-align: center; font-size: 0; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">',
      "product" : [
        '<div class="column" style="--max-table-width: 600px; --max-column-width: 310px; width: 100%; max-width: 310px; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;"><table width="100%" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0; font-family: sans-serif; color: #333333;"><tr> <td style="padding: 0;">',
'<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>',
'<table width="310" align="center"><tr><td width="310" valign="top">',
'<![endif]-->',
'<a href="httpgetwrap|--product_link--">',
'<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>',
'<img src="--image_link--" width="310" alt class="mcbt_image_link" align="center" style="--max-table-width: 600px; --max-column-width: 310px; border: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 310px; height: auto;">',
'</td></tr></table>',
'<div style="display:none;width:0px;max-height:0px;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;height:0;font-size:0;max-height:0;line-height:0;margin:0 auto;">',
'<![endif]-->',
'<img src="--image_link--" alt class="mcbt_image_link" style="border: 0; width: 100%; max-width: 310px; height: auto;">',
'<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>',
'</div>',
'<![endif]-->',
'</a>',
'</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0;"><table class="text_table" align="center" style="border-spacing: 0; font-family: sans-serif; color: #333333; width: 100%; max-width: 310px;"><tr><td class="mcbt_name" style="padding: 0; font-size: 0.8125rem; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center; width: 100%; max-width: 310px;">--name--</td></tr><tr><td class="mcbt_regular_price" style="padding: 0; font-size: 0.8125rem; padding-top: 10px; text-align: center; width: 100%; max-width: 310px;">$--regular_price--</td></tr>',
'</table></td></tr><tr></tr></table></div>'
      ],
      "attributes" : {"image_link":"image_link","product_link":"link","name":"name","regular_price":"regular_price"},
      "footer" : '</td></tr></table><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]></td></tr></table><![endif]--></div></div>',
      "salePricingStyle" : "undefined"
    };
    var defaultProductMarkup = markupFragments["product"].join("");
    
    // Read data from MC
    var data = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@data");
    var mid = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@mid");
    var event_locale = Platform.Variable.GetValue("@event_locale");
    
    // Build the url
    var protocol = "https";
    var hostname = mid + ".recs.igodigital.com";
    var qs = "?item_count=" + settings["maxItems"] + "&sort_by=" + settings["sortBy"] + "&sort_direction=" + settings["sortDirection"];
    var includes = [];
    for (var key in settings["fields"]) {
      if(defaults[key] == null) {
        includes = includes.concat(settings["fields"][key]);
      }
    }
    if(includes.length > 0) {
      qs += "&include=" + includes.join("|")
    }
    if(event_locale){
      qs += "&locale=" + event_locale
    }
    var url = protocol + "://" + hostname + "/" + mid + "/trigger" + qs;
        
    var result = HTTP.Post(url, "application/json", data, []);
    if (result.StatusCode == 200) {
      var response = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);

      // Expose fields in response as Ampscript variables
      for(var responseField in response) {
        var value = response[responseField];
        
        if(responseField === "products" || responseField === "current_cart") {
          var prefix = (responseField === "products") ? "@item_" : "@cart_";
          for(var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
            for(var itemField in value[i]) {
              var name = prefix + itemField + "_" + (i+1);
              var val = value[i][itemField];
              Platform.Variable.SetValue(name, val);
            }
          }
        }
        else if(responseField === "user") {
          var prefix = "@user_";
          for(var userField in value) {
            var name = prefix + userField;
            var val = value[userField];
            Platform.Variable.SetValue(name, val);
          }
        }
        else {
          Platform.Variable.SetValue("@"+responseField, value);
        }
      }
      
      // Use abandoned items or current items?
      var useRecentItems = false;
      if (useRecentItems && response["current_cart"] !== undefined) {
        var products = response["current_cart"];
        if(products.length === 0) {
          Write("User has an empty cart so stop send");
          Platform.Function.RaiseError("Trigger no longer valid - User has an empty cart.", true, "statusCode","3");
        }
      } else {
        var products = response["products"];
      }

      // Exit the send if the user made a purchase since the trigger
      if (response["purchased"] === true) {
        Write("User has purchased so stop send");
        Platform.Function.RaiseError("Trigger no longer valid - User has purchased since trigger.", true, "statusCode","3");
      };
      
      // true to use salePricing style, false if not
      var useSalePricing = false;
      
      // Write email contents
      var content = response["tracking_pixel"];
      content = content + markupFragments["header"].replace('\"', '"');
      content = content + '<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>';
      content = content + '<table>';
      content = content + '<![endif]-->';
      for (var i=0; i < products.length; i++) {
        var product = products[i];
        var productAttributes = markupFragments["attributes"];
        
        content = content + '<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>';
        if(i % 1 === 0) {
          content = content + '<tr>';
        }
        content = content + '<td width="310px" valign="top">';
        content = content + '<![endif]-->';
        
        var productMarkup = defaultProductMarkup;
        if(useSalePricing) {
          if(productMarkup.indexOf("regular_price") > 0 && product["sale_price"] < product["regular_price"] && product["sale_price"] > 0) {
            var matches = productMarkup.match('(class="mcbt_regular_price" style=")(.*?)"');
            if(matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
              productMarkup = productMarkup.replace(matches[0], matches[1] + matches[2] + ' ' + markupFragments["salePricingStyle"] + '"');
            }
          }
          else if(product["sale_price"] <= 0) {
            var matches = productMarkup.match('(class="mcbt_sale_price" style=")(.*?)"');
            if(matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
              productMarkup = productMarkup.replace(matches[0], matches[1] + matches[2] + ' display:none"');
            }
          }
        }
        
        for(var markupKey in productAttributes) {
          var productKey = productAttributes[markupKey];
          var pattern = "--" + markupKey + "--";
          
          var value = product[productKey];
          if (markupKey === "rating") {
            value = Math.round((value / 5) * 98);
          }
          else if (markupKey === "regular_price" || markupKey === "sale_price") {
            var parsed = value.toString().split(".");
            if (parsed.length > 1 && parsed[1].length === 1 && parsed[1] !== "0") {
              value = value.toString() + "0";
            }
          }
          else if (markupKey === "product_link") {
            value = "%%=RedirectTo('" + value + "')=%%";
          }
          
          while(productMarkup.indexOf(pattern) > 0) {
            productMarkup = productMarkup.replace(pattern, function(){return value});
          }
        }
        
        content = content + productMarkup.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
        content = content + '<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>';
        content = content + '</td>';
        if( (i+1) % columnCount === 0 || i === products.length-1) {
          content = content + '</tr>';
        }
        content = content + '<![endif]-->';
      }
      content = content + '<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>';
      content = content + '</table>';
      content = content + '<![endif]-->';
      content = content + markupFragments["footer"].replace('\"', '"');
      
      // Set Markup in Ampscript var
      Platform.Variable.SetValue("@content", content);
    }
    else {
      Write("Unable to retrieve product information: statusCode=" + result.StatusCode);
      Platform.Function.RaiseError("Quit send.", true, "statusCode","3");
    }
  } catch(e) {
    Write(e);
    Platform.Function.RaiseError("Quit send.", true, "statusCode","3");
  } 
</script>

%%=TreatAsContent(@content)=%%
```

I'm not sure where in the above code I can put the any country variables in.

Thanks in advance.